# How to keep one Angular 2 view (login) that deviates from app.component template

Tags: angular

I'm writing an Angular 2 app which contains a fixed header and footer. Since the header and footer are always the same for each view, I figure I can just keep them in app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Header container goes here-->
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <!-- Footer container goes here -->
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
  [...]
```

However the app has one view at the root (a login) which does NOT have the header + footer. If I specify them in app.component.ts they show up at login as well.

Was is the recommended, most elegant way to deal with exception cases like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it with an `*ngIf="showHeader"` to hide it for specific cases.